# Copy file to current directory?

Tags: command-line, files, copy

How to copy a file in current directory? e.g. I have  a file at `/abc/xyz` and I am in the current directory `mno` -- I want to copy a file from `/abc/xyz/file.txt` into `mno`.

cp command:

```
cp /cp_file_path /Destination_path
```

But what about destination path as my current directory?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can refer to the current directory with a dot (`.`).

So in your case:

```
cp /path/to/source.txt .
```

Answer (score 15):

For the destination directory use a single dot '**`.`**'

### Long Answer

From your home directory type the following:

```
rick@dell:~$ mkdir a && mkdir a/b && mkdir a/b/c && mkdir a/b/c2
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ cd a/b/c
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~/a/b/c$ cp /etc/default/grub .
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~/a/b/c$ cp /etc/default/grub ..
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~/a/b/c$ cp /etc/default/grub ../c2
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~/a/b/c$ cd ../../
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~/a$ tree
.
└── b
    ├── c
    │   └── grub
    ├── c2
    │   └── grub
    └── grub

3 directories, 3 files
```

We created 4 directories on one line by using `&&` to join multiple lines together. Then changed to the directory `a/b/c`, which is the current directory for the following copy commands:

- In the first copy command (`cp`) we set the target / destination to our
  current directory (**c**) with `.`.
- In the second copy command we set the directory to the parent
  directory (**b**) with `..`.
- In the third copy command we set the directory to the sibling
  directory (**c2**) with `../c2`

Next we changed directory to our grand-parent directory (**a**) using `cd ../../`.

Finally we use `tree` to show all the directories and files under directory **a**.

Comment: `maybe that's a code '.' eh?`

Comment: It's half of the Morse Code character set :)

Comment: Haha :) But I meant, it looks weird and tiny to just have the '.' -- it should be in `backticks`

Comment: @cat I'm on my computer now and threw in the back ticks, plus parent directory, sibling directory and grandparent directory examples in addition to current directory example. Sorry the original answer was posted a few minutes after user asked as there were no other answers. I was using my phone which is AskUbuntu-challenged :(

Comment: Well, now this answer deserves to be at the top :)